# Trying to read data from War Thunder local host with python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib

Basically I'm using python to send serial data to an arduino so that I can make moving dials using data from the game. This would work because you can use the url "localhost:8111" to give you a list of these stats when ingame. The problem is I'm using urllib and BeautifulSoup but they seem to be blindly reading the source code not giving the data I need.

The data I need comes up when I inspect the element of that page. Other pages seem to suggest that using something to run the HTML in python would fix this but I have found no way of doing this. Any help here would be great thanks.

Comment: Use `urllib2` to get the page, then pass it to `BeautifulSoup` to parse the html , and get the elements that you need

Comment: Whenever I put it into beautifulsoup I get a list of the source code without the data I need. For example:
<div id="state-root">
<div class="caption"><div id="draghandle"></div></div>
<div id="state">
<ul class="connectedState" id="state0"></ul>
<ul class="connectedState" id="state1"></ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

the data I need should be inside the tag <ul class="connectedState" id="state0"></ul> but it's not.

Comment: Can you post your code and the html of the page ?

Comment: For the War Thunder it is simplier parse JSON that provided by requests to the same port 8111. See for example Python library https://github.com/PowerBroker2/WarThunder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the poster but i have been working on this with him. We managed to get it working. In case anyone else is having this problem here is the code that got it to display our speed

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://localhost:8111")
time.sleep(1)
while True:
    elements = driver.find_element_by_id("stt-IAS, km/h")
    print(elements.text)
```

Don't know why the time.sleep is needed but the code doesn't seem to work without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that the page elements are **Dynamic**. (Revealed by JavaScript for example)
Why is this a problem? A: You can't access those tags or data. You'll have to use either a headless/Automated browser ( Learn more about selenium ).

Then make a session through selenium and keep feeding the data the way you wanted to the Arduino.

Summary: If you ***inspect elements*** you can see the tag, if you go to **view source** you cant see it. This can't be solved using ***bs4*** or ***requests alone***. You'll have to use a module called Selenium or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/WarThunder_Telemetry) is a Python module that you can use to get all air vehicle telemetry data from War Thunder localhost server pages "indicators" and "status". The contents of each of these pages are static JSON descriptions of the vehicle's current telemetry values.

The Python package uses the requests module to query the localhost server for the data, converts the returned JSON data into dictionaries, and then consolidates all the data into a singular telemetry dictionary. This data can then be used for other Python processes such as datalogging or graphing.